# GIT define simple conflict-resolving strategy

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I came across sitaution, where developers on their own branches will modify one file - it's some kind of global file which is generated automatically.

The thing is, that this automatic generation occurs every times at the end of a file. So, file on remote repo looks like:

```
this is first line.
```

Then, two developers on two different branches might have:

```
this is first line.
this was added by developer A.
```

and

```
this is first line.
this was added by developer B.
```

That's all. Clearly, there will be conflict when merging.

But resolution is simple: always take one side, then the other side (order does not matter), so the valid result might be:

```
this is first line.
this was added by developer B.
this was added by developer A.
```

as well as

```
this is first line.
this was added by developer A.
this was added by developer B.
```

This is because the generated parts are completely independant of each other, thus we just want them to be merged like this.

But, still, when merging we will ALWAYS have to megre it manually, which is not so comfortable in day to day work.

Is there any way to set "default way of merging conflicts in PARTICULAR file" in GIT ?

I was trying to employ `git rerere` but it is based on context, which unfortunately changes with every commit. So it can't automatically resolve such conflicts.

I cannot also merge with `strategy-option` because I cannot set it to mixed (only mine or theirs chagnes). And it has to be done manually for one particular file.

So what would be the best way?

CONTEXT:

Very simplified, I need a class that returns string with locale-specific string. So I need static properties like:

```
public static string HelloWorld => _locale == "SPAIN" ? "Hola mundo" : "Hello world";
```

It says just to return spanish version of a string, when locale is "SPAIN", english version for others.

I have tool, where I type property name and translations (tool helps me finding duplicate names, suggests translations etc.). After that, it defines property automatically. But generated property is always at the end of a file, thus, very easy to get conflicts.

Comment: *"some kind of global file which is generated automatically"* - why is a generated file under version control? What does it contain, what's it *for*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because it is auto generated code, which is very relevant to application - we have just more comfortable way of defining the code :)

Comment: autogenerated code can be autogenerated after you cloned the repository. Also, I view it as data (as opposed to code). I am too on the side of "do not version it"

Comment: @jonrsharpe Look at this like this: I define with custom, comfy tool that I need property "Prop" on the class and it should return "Hello world". Custom tool generated this property and it is ready to use throughout the application.

Comment: @DaemonPainter We must have it up to date when developing, so nobody tries to do what is already done.

Comment: but is autogenerated... just have it be generated locally before compiling or run. It avoids conflicts (and, most importantly, it avoids using data that someone changed and _cannot_ be retrieved by autogeneration...)

Comment: @DaemonPainter It is generated based on user (mine or collegaues) action. We need to supply data for it to be autogenerated. Each action needs separate input. The way you suggest, every week or so, I would have spend hours generating this file.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to provide some more context? This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731). *"I define with custom, comfy tool"* - you're pretty much describing writing code in an IDE!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, done it.

Comment: This kind of merge is usually called a *union merge*, and as [seumasmac answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64970057/1256452), you can get this in Git with a simple declaration in your `.gitattributes`. Note that it's crucial that order *not* matter as union merge makes no promises about ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `.gitattributes` file with the following content:

```
myfile.md merge=union
```

(with the correct filename obviously: it's often helpful if you include one in your question so people answering can refer to it)

Comment: It seems to be working exactly as I wished it to :) Thanks

Comment: @MichałTurczyn no worries, glad it worked as you expected!